# Angular switchMap on observable never triggers

Tags: angular, observable

I want to implement a search component as in Angular Tutorial.

**Problem :**

The `search` method fires and modifies `searchTerms: Subject<string>` but `switchMap` never triggers.

**Code:**

**Imports**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { SearchService } from "./search.service";

import { Observable }        from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Subject }           from 'rxjs/Subject';

// Observable class extensions
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';

// Observable operators
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/debounceTime';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/distinctUntilChanged';

import {Suggest} from "./suggest";
```

**Decorator**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'search-engine',
  templateUrl: 'search-engine.component.html'
})
```

**Component**

```
export class SearchEngineComponent implements OnInit {

  suggestions: Observable<Suggest[]>;
  private searchTerms = new Subject<string>();

  constructor(private searchService: SearchService) {  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.suggestions = this.searchTerms
      .debounceTime(300)
      .distinctUntilChanged()
      .switchMap(term => {
        console.log(term);
        return Observable.of<Suggest[]>([]);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
        return Observable.of<Suggest[]>([]);
      });
  }

  search(term: string): void {
    this.searchTerms.next(term);
  }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<input #searchBox id="search-box" (keyup)="search(searchBox.value)">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to subscribe to the Observable, if you don't subscribe, nothing happens.

**Edit:**

There's another case where you can declare and Observable in the view and subscribe implicitly via the `async` pipe, which is what is happening here:

```
<div id="search-component">
  <h4>Hero Search</h4>
  <input #searchBox id="search-box" (keyup)="search(searchBox.value)" />
  <div>
    <div *ngFor="let hero of heroes | async"
         (click)="gotoDetail(hero)" class="search-result" >
      {{hero.name}}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

More on the `async` pipe [here](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe)

Comment: I agree with you. But in the tutorial : https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt6#add-the-ability-to-search-by-name I don't find where we subscribe to the Observable.. Can you show me how?

Comment: You save me, thanks :) So in the case where I haven't a HTML template with * | async *, I must add .subscribe( //do something ) between .switchMap & .catch. Is it?

Comment: No, it's right after `catch`. You can't chain more operators after `subscribe()`.

Comment: Where you put the `.subscribe` I believe is not important even although i always put right after `switchMap`. I recommend you put `.filter` before `switchMap` to check if `term` is not empty or to validate your conditions.